# Query to export a table from SQL to Excel File

Tags: mysql, excel, database, export

What query to use to export a table from MySQL into an Excel file?
I have been trying this query, but it doesn't work:

```
select * 
from cl.Duplicate_Patients 
into outfile 'D:\test_folder\duplicate_patients.xlsx';
```

Moreover, can we export messages of a query into a csv or Excel file?

Comment: If this is for personal testing. I would suggest 3rd party tools like datagrip.

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't work? Is it throwing an error? if so please share the error message. If the problem is that is not returning the expected output, please let us know both, the actual output and the expected one.

Comment: Hi it gives the following error,, "Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 353
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'into'." and it saves the error into the file.